# SpatialPolygonDataFrame to raster while keeping categorical values

Tags: shapefile, r, rasterization, rstudio

I have a SpatialPolygonDataFrame which I need to convert to raster in R while keeping the categorical values of the polygon. I have tried various approaches but I have always either lost the values or converted them to numerical, which is not what I want. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Factors are stored as numbers, so a raster of categorical values is just a raster of numbers with a lookup-table for the labels (which is the same as a standard vector of factors in R).

To do what you want using modern R spatial classes, use `sf` and `terra`:

```
 library(sf)
 library(terra)
```

Read the shape:

```
 sh = st_read("./kasanka habitats.shp")
```

The "Coverage" variable (which I think is what you want to rasterize) is character at this point so we convert it to factor:

```
 sh$Coverage = as.factor(sh$Coverage)
```

create a basis for rasterizing based on the extent of the shape:

```
 y = rast(ext(sh),200,200)
```

now rasterize:

```
 tsh = rasterize(as(sh,"SpatVector"), y,field="Coverage")
```

and plot:

```
 plot(tsh)
```

[image]

Note this is still a raster of numbers, so if you try writing it to some file format you might lose the labels.

Answer (score 0):

Here is Spacedman's solution using a more direct path

```
library(terra)
sh = vect("./kasanka habitats.shp")
y = rast(sh, 200, 200)
tsh = rasterize(sh, y, field="Coverage")
```